# Ambiguity in Grammars

Tags: racket, ambiguous, ambiguous-grammar

I'm learning about ambiguity in grammars and I need a little help to understand better. Here is a grammar:

```
<S> ::= if <S> then <S>
<S> ::= if <S> then <S> else <S>
<S> ::= a
```

Using a parse tree or left-most derivation, how can I show that this grammar is ambiguous?

Comment: Try nesting `if` statements in different combinations, and for each one think of whether you can put "parentheses" on it multiple conflicting ways

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
if a then if a then a else a
```

You could consider grouping it either of the following two ways:

```
(if a then (if a then a else a))
```

or

```
(if a then (if a then a) else a)
```

Both are possible with the grammar you provide, so it's ambiguous.